# Track iOS mobile installs from Facebook ad

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, analytics, user-tracking

I have created app on Facebook and add set for the app and integrated the SDK in my Xcode, configure my plist and relevant code below in AppDelegate:-

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                      annotation:annotation];
}
```

On Facebook Under the app there are some menu:

1. Status & Review menu is pending
2. App Details menu is left pending
   (Red icon for that pending part in both the menu's)

For the First Point, In this Below is mentioned, 
**iOS App
Please provide a version of your iOS app for our team to review.**
for above i need to provide simulator build and its for reference on Facebook is that

If you create an app that uses Facebook Login you need to submit for review. See Review Guidelines.

I just need to track how many apps download from Facebook ad and I am not providing doing any login in the app for the Facebook.

But if I close app details part. How will I know when my app goes live and people intalls it form Facebook add it will track.

Any help/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to track mobile app installs you do NOT need to have your application reviewed. You only need to submit for review if you want your application to be listed in the Facebook App Center (uses you App Details Page) or if you are using Login and need certain permissions.

In order to make your application live to the public all you need to do is go here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/review-status/ and toggle the switch I have highlighted below and it will be live to the public:

[image: Status & Review]

This means that the public can start using your application. Just so you know you can also ensure that your application is set up correctly by using the [App Ads Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/).